# Sass convert variable to string

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I have something like this

```
$theme: "default";
@import "styles/themes/#{$theme}/main";
```

But it does not work, maybe in import sass have problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working according to the [Sass @import docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import): "Imports may contain #{} interpolation, but only with certain restrictions. It’s not possible to dynamically import a Sass file based on a variable; interpolation is only for CSS imports. As such, it only works with url() imports."

Comment: Is there then better solution for my problem?

Comment: and exactly what's your problem. Do you want to create several `main.css`with one theme in each or one `main.css`with several themes included?